# Backup ext4 on LUKS to an external drive if the size of the target drive is less than the size of the source drive

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, dd, ext4, luks

I have a few spare 1TB marked SSDs that I'd like to use for my primary NAND backup. I'd prefer to have `dd` for dumping everything as it is - but the tricky part is that my NAND has about 1.5 GB more space than the would-be-backup SSDs. I have about 200Gb of free space on that NAND at the moment, so from that perspective everything should work fine.

Is there any way I can safely/reliably use `dd` to copy everything from the NAND to an SSD without losing some data ( the NAND drive is in full-encrypted LUKS mode )?

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you have described what you are asking.

You can VERY LIKELY do this if you use compression, but that will make the backup difficult to read. You also need to ensure that empty disk space on the source is zero'd out(so it compresses) if the data you are saving is not very compressible.  It is possible to use a command line that invokes dd in the transfer  but dd is not needed here.

If this is a regular event the best way would be (after making a backup) to shrink the source filesystem - and maybe even the partition so the source is not bigger then the target. It is quite practical to shrink ext partitions but it needs yo be done offline.  As LUKS stores its metadata at the start of the disk im 99% sure you can truncate a LUKS device without breaking the LUKS layer.

There may  however  be an alternative solution depending on your partition layout.  If you have a boot and/or swap partition you dont care about and which is larger then 1.5 gigs, just back up the backing partion for the LUKS system rather then the whole disk.(I cant advise fully how you do this as it depends on if you have lvm installed)